# git install on jenkins slaves

Tags: git, jenkins

I have both Linux and Windows slaves. I would like to install Git automatically on a slave first time the master needs to run git on it. how do you tell Jenkins to install it properly on Win or Linux, if possible at all ?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you need to check if which git returns something (which git.exe on Windows, provided you have installed [GoW -- Gnu on Windows -- commands](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki/)).

If which fails, then see "[**Set Up Your Git Environment**](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/git/)"

On Linux:

```
sudo yum install git-core       # RedHat
sudo apt-get install git-core   # Ubuntu
```

On Windows:

Download and untar the [portable version of msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list).
You can script it, using the curl command included in Gow, but for uncompressing a 7z archive, you might need [Peazip installed](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/) (it also comes as a [portable installation](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-portable.html), a simple zip archive).

Comment: Thanks VonC - the portable version worked fine for me. I was able to deploy it with Jenkins. now I am stuck with an ssh issue from a windows slave to my git repository. spent hours on this to no avail.I'll might send a different question on this.